# Adding custom html to Header in WebGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, text, header, webgrid

I'm trying to add a custom header for an MVC3 WebGrid.

The header property only allows for string, and any HTML is escaped.

My current grid razor view is as follows:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5);
            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);

            @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "data_table-sorter",
                alternatingRowStyle: "odd",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(header:"Select<span class=\"fi fi_gear\"></span>\"" , style: "table-select-col has-menu", canSort: false, format: @<input type="checkbox" value="@item.Id" />),
                grid.Column("Name", "Briefing Book Name", canSort: true, style: "dj_sortable-table-column"),
                grid.Column("Format", "Format", canSort: true, style: "dj_sortable-table-column") 
));
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style individual headers in the current version of the WebGrid, you will have to use client-side code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

for all header element....................

$("#gridContent").find('table thead tr a')

and then apply style any this u want [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869178/mvc3-webgrid-formatting-or-styling-column-headers)

.addClass()
.append()

for individual header.....................

actually this is applying style of rowcell to the headercell

var headerCells = $("#gridContent table tr th");

```
var firstRowCells = $("#gridContent table tr td");

$.each(firstRowCells, function (index, value) {
    $(headerCells[index]).addClass($(firstRowCells[index]).attr("class"));
});
```

also see
[MVC3 WebGrid Formatting or Styling Column Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869178/mvc3-webgrid-formatting-or-styling-column-headers)

[How to add Html inside ASP.NET MVC 3 WebGrid Column Name (Header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683559/how-to-add-html-inside-asp-net-mvc-3-webgrid-column-name-header)

[MVC3 WebGrid Formatting or Styling Column Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869178/mvc3-webgrid-formatting-or-styling-column-headers)